# What's the equivalent of Alt-left/right arrow key like Eclipse in IntelilJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>-></kbd> to move between places you were. What is the equivalent in Intellij?

Answer (score 33):

It is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. See [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-navigated-items.html).

Comment: This is bad if you use Intellij within a VMware Player, since `CTRL + ALT` is the shortcut to jump to the parent OS with your mouse cursor. Intellij shortcuts are even worse on a german keyboard layout.

Comment: This does not work in some Windows environment with Intel graphics display as this shortcut is mapped to modify the display

Answer (score 11):

I confirmed it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>(<kbd>→</kbd>) on Mac OS X.
Command + Option + Left(Right)

Just for additional information.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest just go and select eclipse shortcuts option instead of default provided by IntelliJ idea ide

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can also change default shortcuts option to eclipse shortcuts option -
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> select Eclipse in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.3 and i could only make the navigation work by using: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I got this from IntelliJ site, I'm sure it will be helpful:

To navigate backwards, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. To navigate forward, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

To navigate to the last edited location, press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>.

To find the current caret location in the editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This action might be helpful if you do not want to scroll through a large file.

However, you can press the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys to achieve the same result.

To highlight a word at the caret you are trying to locate, select Edit | Find | Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret from the main menu.

To see on what element the caret is currently positioned, press <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

To move caret between matching code block braces, press <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

To navigate between code blocks, press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.